# Member method consting in Java?

Tags: java, c++

In C++, a member method can be const if it does not modify the class. For example:

```
class Foo {
public:
  float getValue() const;
};
```

Is there something similar I must do in Java classes? How exactly does consting work in Java? (Aside from adding the final keyword before a member variable declaration and initializing it)

Thanks

Comment: I know you've already accepted an answer, but there's more to this than simply "no." In case it's of use to you, I've added a fuller answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Java lacks a const qualifier, you can achieve some of the same ends with read-only interfaces and immutable types.

So, instead of qualifying a reference as const, you could specify its type to be a read-only interface type.

For example, given these two interfaces:

```
    public interface A {
       int getValue(); 
    }

    public interface MutableA extends A {
       void setValue( int i );
    }
```

Then this method's argument is similar to a const-qualified pointer/reference in C++.

```
    public void foo( A a )
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there something similar I must do in Java classes?

Nope.

> How exactly does consting work in Java?

It doesn't exist in Java.

Answer (score 3):

There really is no notion of `const` in Java beyond the `final` keyword as you've mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, Java has nothing at all that's analogous to const methods. Since there are no const references, there is no need for them.

`final` is like `const` for primitive data or reference variables, but it doesn't imply anything about referred-to objects.